# Sliding window time series data with Python Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, sliding-window

I have data that looks like:

```
 1495573445.162, 0, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
 1495573445.172, 0, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
 1495573445.182, 0, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
 1495573445.192, 0, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
 1495573445.202, 0, 0.021194, 0.012161, -0.994705, 1
 1495573445.212, 0, 0.019638, 0.013718, -0.994019, 1
 1495573445.222, 0, 0.019440, 0.010803, -0.994476, 1
 1495573445.232, 0, 0.018112, 0.010849, -0.993073, 1
 1495573445.242, 0, 0.020157, 0.011154, -0.994644, 1
 1495573445.252, 0, 0.020340, 0.010040, -0.995804, 1
 1495573445.262, 0, 0.017792, 0.009857, -0.996078, 1
 1495573445.272, 0, 0.020538, 0.010239, -0.994858, 1
```

This is accelerometer data where the data frame columns are labeled `"Time stamp"`, `"Time skipped"`, `"x"`, `"y"`, `"z"`, and `"label"` with the index set to `"Time stamp"`.

The sampling rate is around 100Hz. How should I create a sliding window in this case?

I came up with this:

```
def sliding_window(data, window_size, step_size):
    data = pd.rolling_window(data, window_size)
    data = data[step_size - 1 :: step_size]
    print data
    return data
```

I doubt this is the correct implementation, and I don't know what to set window_size and step_size given that I have a 100Hz sampling rate.

Comment: The values of those params depend on the noise in the source you are using. You need to just try some options and see how they work. You want to determine how much smoothing you need.

Comment: I tried using sample difference to smooth the data. The data is actually pretty clean.

Comment: But is that the correct implementation regardless of what I set the parameters to?